# Appending user-defined modules for automatic searching

Tags: python, import, module

I crated in the directory `site-packages` in Windows my own directories and placed where some Python files.

Can I import them naming only modules or do I need to do some additional manipulations to make the directories and modules visible?

Comment: Python docs: [The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Comment: @ekhumoro It is a useless reference because reading the provided text it is still unclear how to add user defined modules. It seems who wrote the documentation for Python are unable to use the human language.

Comment: The linked documentation does answer your question (as it is currently written). If you have more specific requirements, please edit your question and add the relevant details. (NB: to understand in more general terms how Python imports work, see Python docs: [Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)).

Comment: @ekhumoro It is a very bad documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to import them if they're within the `site-packages` directory. That being said: the docs state this is "by convention" and installation-dependent; this seems to imply that in specific installations this might not be the case, I suppose?

More broadly, you should be able to import them if they're within any of the directories in [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), and the `site-packages` directory is usually (by convention etc) part of it by default, as stated. You can also add custom directories "permanently" by modifying the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Edit in response to OP's clarification:
If you have a directory `a` within `site-packages`, and inside that directory you have module `b`, then the syntax to import it would be `import a.b`, or `from a.b import *`.
In order to enable the `import b`/`from b import *` syntax, you'd need to have that file in the base directory of any of the directories in your `sys.path`. So, for instance, placing the module `b` straight in `site-packages`, and not inside the `a` directory; or by adding whichever directory `b` is in (`a` for example) into your `sys.path`. This could either be achieved with a dynamic modification of `sys.path` in your script itself, or "permanently" by modifying the PYTHONPATH environment variable to contain that directory, as mentioned above.

Comment: It is still unclear if I will place modules in subdirectories of the directory site-packages- will they be visible?

Comment: Ah; do you mean, for instance, if you have a directory in `site-packages` named `a` and then another few directories `a/inner1`, `a/inner2`, etc which are the modules themselves? If so, then the "inner" modules (the subdirectories) should be accessible with `import a.nested1`, `import a.nested2`, etc. (This should likewise be correct for every directory within your `sys.path`.)

Comment: If what you want is for those modules to be directly accessible (without the preceding `a`), then maybe what you're looking for really is the addition of a "custom site-packages" for your own modules, which can be added to your PYTHONPATH, as I mentioned. I hope I understand what you're asking correctly.

Comment: I mean the following. I created for example in the directory site-packages directory a and placed where a module b.py. Will be it enough then to write from b import *?

Comment: No: it would have to be `from a.b import *`. If you want it to be just `from b import *`, you'd need to either place `b.py` in `site-packages` itself, or add whichever directory `b.py` is in into your PYTHONPATH (or `sys.path`).